# Update embedded mongoose document in array

Tags: arrays, mongoose, document

Lets say that I have the following document in the books collection:

```javascript
{
  _id:0 ,
  item: "TBD",
  stock: 0,
  info: { publisher: "1111", pages: 430 },
  tags: [ "technology", "computer" ],
  ratings: [ { _id:id1, by: "ijk", rating: 4 }, {_id:id2 by: "lmn", rating: 5 } ],
  reorder: false
}
```

I would like to update the value of `ratings[k].rating` and all I know is the id of the collection and the _id of the objects existing in the array ratings.

The tutorial of mongoDB has the following example that uses the position of the object inside the array but I suppose that if the update can only be done by knowing the position, this means that I firstly have to find the position and then proceed with the update? Can I do the update with only one call and if so how I can do that?

```javascript
db.books.update(    
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $inc: { stock: 5 },
     $set: {
       item: "ABC123",
       "info.publisher": "2222",
       tags: [ "software" ],
       "ratings.1": { by: "xyz", rating: 3 }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: Do you mean you know values of `_id` and another `_id` inside `ratings`? And you want to update the rating inside ratings. Right?

Comment: Exactly this is what i mean... I have tried different ways  but none of them actually  update the value of the attribute rating that I want.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer; I think this is what you want to do with `mongoose`.

```
Books.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: 1,
        'ratings._id': id1
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'ratings.$.rating' : 3
        }
    }, function(err, book){
        // Response
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) may help you:

```
db.books.update(
   // find book by `book_id` with `rating_id` specified
   { "_id": book_id, "ratings._id": rating_id },

   // set new `value` for that rating
   { $set: { 'ratings.$.rating': value }} 
);
```

[$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) will save *position* of matched document.

Comment: I am getting the following error (code 16837): [MongoError: cannot use the part (ratings of ratings._id) to traverse the element ((ratings: [Obj1], [Obj2]))